# Office JS - Unable to get context.sync() out of for loop which is hurting performance

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I am currently developing an add-in for word using the office javascript library.

The following function is meant to split the document text into sentences while ensuring that these sentences can span across paragraphs (The built in library function (`getTextRanges()`) splits on paragraph marks regardless of whether the delimiter (in this case ".") is present. Essentially, I want to divvy up the document text into sentences based only on when the next "." is. There is also included some code to protect certain "." from being interpreted as the end of a sentence (e.g. if you refer to section 7.4 in the middle of a sentence you don't want it to treat it as the end of the sentence).

I have a for loop that searches each sentence made by the `getTextRanges()` function. It compares the adjacent sentence, and if both don't contain a "." it merges the sentences (ranges) into one single sentence (range). It then keeps checking the next range made by `getTextRanges()` until a "." is present, including that range with a "." as the final range in the merged range. It then resets and starts the process over with the next range by `getTextRanges()` until every range from `getTextRanges()` has been looped through.

The problem is, for some reason I can't move the `await context.sync()` out of the for loop without generating an error that the "text" property cannot be loaded. Having it present in the for loop greatly reduces performance. I have tried to follow this guide for splitting up the loop: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/correlated-objects-pattern. However, it seems that the issue lies in the `expandTo` function creating the merged range. Somehow the merged range cannot be assigned or pushed to an array without the context.sync() having been called before.

Any help or nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

NB: Sorry for my apparent bad JS skills, I am quite new and still learning.

Here is my entire function:

```
var global_sentences3_text = []
var global_sentences3_ranges = []
var global_sentences_real = null
async function realsentenizer() {
  await Word.run(async (context) => {
    const body = context.document.body.getRange();
    body.load("text");
    await context.sync();

    //making sure we are not splitting on period in these cases: "clause 5.6" or "registration no. 555"
    var ranges_to_protect = body.search("[0-99].[0-99]", {matchWildcards: true, matchCase: false})
    var ranges_to_protect2 = body.search("[Nn][Oo].", {matchWildcards: true, matchCase: false})

    ranges_to_protect.load('text')
    ranges_to_protect2.load('text')
    await context.sync()

    var saved_text = []
    var saved_text2 = []
    for (let i = 0; i < ranges_to_protect.items.length ; i++) {
      saved_text.push(ranges_to_protect.items[i].text)
      ranges_to_protect.items[i].insertText('[PROTECTEDDOT]','Replace')
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < ranges_to_protect2.items.length ; i++) {
      saved_text2.push(ranges_to_protect2.items[i].text)
      ranges_to_protect2.items[i].insertText('[PROTECTEDDOT]','Replace')
    }

    //splitting bodytext on "."
    const sentences = body.getTextRanges(["."], false);
    sentences.load('text')
    
    global_sentences_real = sentences
    
    await context.sync();

    const new_ranges =[]
    var saved_range = sentences.items[0]

    // Loop through the ranges, checking adjacent pairs
    for (let i = 1; i < sentences.items.length ; i++) {

      if (sentences.items[i].text.includes(".") == false && saved_range.text.includes(".") == false){
        console.log('CHANGED')
        const extended_range = saved_range.expandTo(sentences.items[i])
        extended_range.load('text')
        await context.sync()

        saved_range = extended_range
      } else {
        console.log('NOT CHANGED')
        const extended_range2 = saved_range.expandTo(sentences.items[i])
        extended_range2.load('text')
        await context.sync()

        new_ranges.push(extended_range2)
        saved_range = sentences.items[i+1]
      }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < ranges_to_protect.items.length ; i++) {
      ranges_to_protect.items[i].insertText(saved_text[i],'Replace')
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < ranges_to_protect2.items.length ; i++) {
      ranges_to_protect2.items[i].insertText(saved_text2[i],'Replace')
    }
    
    await context.sync()

    for (let sentence of new_ranges) {
      sentence.load('text')
      await context.sync()
      global_sentences3_text.push(sentence.text)
      sentence.track()
      global_sentences3_ranges.push(sentence)
    }

    global_sentences_real.track()
    
  await context.sync()
  console.log('Succesfully sentenized')
  });
}
```

This is the for loop generating the issue:

```
const new_ranges =[]
    var saved_range = sentences.items[0]

    // Loop through the ranges, checking adjacent pairs
    for (let i = 1; i < sentences.items.length ; i++) {

      if (sentences.items[i].text.includes(".") == false && saved_range.text.includes(".") == false){
        console.log('CHANGED')
        const extended_range = saved_range.expandTo(sentences.items[i])
        extended_range.load('text')
        await context.sync()

        saved_range = extended_range
      } else {
        console.log('NOT CHANGED')
        const extended_range2 = saved_range.expandTo(sentences.items[i])
        extended_range2.load('text')
        await context.sync()

        new_ranges.push(extended_range2)
        saved_range = sentences.items[i+1]
      }
    }
```

T

Comment: the error that the text-property is not available happens even if I remove the loading of the text in the for loop.

Comment: What is the exact wording of the error? Does it vary depending on whether the load() is there or not?

Comment: This is the full error code: "Unhandled Promise Rejection: RichApi.Error: Property 'text' is not available. Before reading the property's value, call the load method on the containing object and call "context.sync()" on the associated request context."

It does not vary depending on the presence of load()

Comment: Hmmm. That error means that there either is no load() call before the context.sync or there is no context.sync between the load() call and trying to read the `range.text`. Try again with the context.sync removed from the loop. But put a breakpoint on the load() call. Then step through the code line by line till you get to the first line that reads the range's text. You should hit a context.sync somewhere in between. Also, you have a 2nd `for` loop with a context.sync in it.

Comment: Also, aside from performance problem when context.sync is in the loop, does the code do what you want it to do?

Comment: The code does what I want it to do yes. I tried adding breakpoints for each line, and i  can complete the first loop with i=1. The second loop it breaks at the if statement. Probably because it has to access the text attribute of the "saved_range" which in reality is the new range created by the expandTo function. I think that this for some reason requires that the text property be loaded again, even though the range consist of two ranges that it already knows the text of and as such have only merged them.

Comment: I have fixed it now! I just removed the second conditional in the if statement (saved_range.text.includes(".") == false), and my code still performs its intended function, which is obvious when I look at it now. The way I set it up, it was redundant. However, I still think the issue represented here may have revealed a fault in the library? Or is that just my unexperienced eyes.

Answer (score 0):

This is too complicated to put in a comment, but I can edit this later as needed. See what happens if you replace the code in your second code block with the following:

```
const new_ranges =[]
let saved_range = sentences.items[0]

let extended_range = {};

// Loop through the ranges, checking adjacent pairs
for (let i = 1; i < sentences.items.length ; i++) {

  if (sentences.items[i].text.includes(".") == false && saved_range.text.includes(".") == false){
    console.log('CHANGED')
    extended_range = saved_range.expandTo(sentences.items[i])
    extended_range.load('text')
    saved_range = extended_range
  } else {
    console.log('NOT CHANGED')
    extended_range = saved_range.expandTo(sentences.items[i])
    extended_range.load('text')
    new_ranges.push(extended_range)
    saved_range = sentences.items[i+1]
  }      
}    
await context.sync();
```

Comment: First and foremost, thank you for taking the time to help. Unfortunately, the exact same error as described above still happens.

Comment: It is fixed now - see my comment above, much thanks for the help anyway!